# Hide the column add to cart in the slider of previously viewed products

Tags: magento2

How can I hide the column with the add item to cart button if the price of the item is zero in the slider of previously viewed items?

listing.html code

```
<div if="hasData()"
     class="widget-product recently-viewed" css="additionalClasses">
    <div class="main-heading">
        <h2 class="heading-title block-title">
            <span role="heading"
                  aria-level="2"
                  text="label"></span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="category-products block-content">
        <div class="widget-products-grid">
            <ol class="product-items owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <li class="product-item" repeat="foreach: filteredRows, item: '$row'">
                    <div class="product-item-info">
                        <div class="product-show">
                            <fastForEach args="data: getRegion('general-area'), as: '$col'" >
                                <render args="$col.getBody()"></render>
                            </fastForEach>
                            <if args="getRegion('action-primary-area')().length || getRegion('action-secondary-area')().length">
                                <div class="product-btn">
                                    <div class="row no-gutters text-center">
                                        <if args="getRegion('action-primary-area')().length">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                                    <fastForEach args="data: getRegion('action-primary-area'), as: '$col'" >
                                                        <render args="$col.getBody()"></render>
                                                    </fastForEach>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </if>
                                        <if args="getRegion('action-secondary-area')().length">
                                            <fastForEach args="data: getRegion('action-secondary-area'), as: '$col'" >
                                                <render args="$col.getBody()"></render>
                                            </fastForEach>
                                        </if>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </if>
                        </div>

                        <div class="product-item-details">
                            <fastForEach args="data: getRegion('details-area'), as: '$col'" >
                                <render args="$col.getBody()"></render>
                            </fastForEach>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ko if: sliderInit($index) --><!-- /ko -->
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```